# How do I combine two ModelForms in one view with the fields displayed in an arbitrary order?

Tags: python, django, forms

Let's say I have the following two Django models.

```
class FruitBasket(models.Model):
    apple = models.CharField()
    strawberry = models.CharField()

class VegetableGarden(models.Model):
    celery = models.CharField()
    turnip = models.CharField()
```

If I want to create one view for a user to create both a `FruitBasket` and a `VegetableGarden` in the same form, I can create one `ModelForm` for each and pass them to my view like so:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ fruit_form.as_p }}
    {{ vegetable_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This will allow the user to enter the apple, strawberry, celery, and turnip fields, in that order.

What if, instead, I wanted to display the fields in the order turnip, strawberry, celery, and then apple? I want to avoid writing a whole new `Form` class, since I would have to duplicate all of the validation (`clean` functions). Is there a way to arbitrarily decide the order of fields when combining two forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ form.as_p }}` is just one of the many ways to display a form. You can output the widget of each individual field using the `{{ form.name_of_field }}` syntax:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ vegetable_form.turnip }}
    {{ fruit_form.strawberry }}
    {{ vegetable_form.celery }}
    {{ fruit_form.apple }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Note that this won't display errors. Individual error messages are available under `{{ form.name_of_field.errors }}`, and you can access the forms error messages using `{{ form.errors }}`.

Take a look at [customizing the form template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template) for more information on the subject.